# extract innerHTML at a specific depth into DOM tree structure

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I try to extract, at a specific depth level, innerHTML text between the tags `<span class="MATH">` and `</span>` with `queryselectorAll` on a HTML page.

The problem is that these tags appears at different depth into the tree structure of DOM. Here's an example of the HTML page :

```
<span class="MATH"><img width="75" height="37" align="MIDDLE" border="0" src="img1909.gif" alt="$ \mathbf{V_{M}}(M')$"></span> le vecteur <!-- MATH
 $\mathbf{V}(M')$
 -->
<span class="MATH"><img width="59" height="37" align="MIDDLE" border="0" src="img1906.gif" alt="$ \mathbf{V}(M')$"></span> transport&#233; parall&#232;lement au point <span class="MATH"><img width="24" height="17" align="BOTTOM" border="0" src="img232.gif" alt="$ M$"></span>. Le vecteur :</p>

<p></p>
<p></p>
<div align="CENTER" class="mathdisplay"><a name="eq398"></a><!-- MATH
 \begin{equation}
\mathbf{V_{M}}(M')-\mathbf{V}(M)=\text{d}\,\mathbf{V}
\end{equation}
 -->
<table class="equation" cellpadding="0" width="100%" align="CENTER">
<tr valign="MIDDLE">
<td nowrap align="CENTER"><span class="MATH"><img width="169" height="38" align="MIDDLE" border="0" src="img1910.gif" alt="$\displaystyle \mathbf{V_{M}}(M')-\mathbf{V}(M)=$">d<img width="23" height="34" align="MIDDLE" border="0" src="img1911.gif" alt="$\displaystyle \,\mathbf{V}$"></span></td>
<td nowrap class="eqno" width="10" align="RIGHT">
(<span class="arabic">5</span>.<span class="arabic">61</span>)</td></tr>
</table></div>
<br clear="ALL"><p></p>

<p>
est appel&#233; <b>la diff&#233;rentielle absolue du vecteur <!-- MATH
 $\mathbf{V}$
 -->
<span class="MATH"><img width="20" height="17" align="BOTTOM" border="0" src="img835.gif" alt="$ \mathbf{V}$"></span></b>.
```

I would like to select only the tags `<span class="MATH">` located into 
the `<table class="equation"><tr><td>` and `</td>` : this will give for example with the above HTML page :

```
 <img width="169" height="38" align="MIDDLE" border="0" src="img1910.gif" alt="$\displaystyle \mathbf{V_{M}}(M')-\mathbf{V}(M)=$">d<img width="23" height="34" align="MIDDLE" border="0" src="img1911.gif" alt="$\displaystyle \,\mathbf{V}$">
```

to do that, I tried :

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('table.equation tr td span.MATH'),function(span_block) {
console.log(span_block.innerHTML); });
```

but it doesn't work.

I tried to also :

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('table.equation >  span.MATH'),function(span_block) {
console.log(span_block.innerHTML); });
```

but it fails too.

With the `queryselectorAll` command, how to specify the depth (of DOM structure) at which I want to extract the good `<span class="MATH">` ?

Inversely, If I want only select the `<span class"MATH">` at the first depth level, i.e in my example :

```
<span class="MATH"><img width="75" height="37" align="MIDDLE" border="0" src="img1909.gif" alt="$ \mathbf{V_{M}}(M')$"></span> le vecteur <!-- MATH
     $\mathbf{V}(M')$
     -->
    <span class="MATH"><img width="59" height="37" align="MIDDLE" border="0" src="img1906.gif" alt="$ \mathbf{V}(M')$"></span> transport&#233; parall&#232;lement au point <span class="MATH"><img width="24" height="17" align="BOTTOM" border="0" src="img232.gif" alt="$ M$"></span>

 <span class="MATH"><img width="20" height="17" align="BOTTOM" border="0" src="img835.gif" alt="$ \mathbf{V}$"></span></b>
```

How could I do this ?

Thanks

Comment: indenting your html and stripping all noisy attributes might make your code examples more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.querySelectorAll("table.equation tr td span.MATH");
```

Or just

```
document.querySelectorAll(".equation .MATH");
```

Should work. Are you making sure you run your code after the document has loaded?
(Put your scripts at the bottom of the html does the trick)

http://jsfiddle.net/vt52bauu/3/

Comment: Thank you and inversely, how can I select only the <span class="MATH"> of the first depth level ?

Comment: You can use `>` for finding direct descendants. So `document.querySelectorAll("body > span.MATH");` for example. Replace `body` with whatever element the spans are inside.